# Facebook access_token not valid

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am building a little website for an event. The idea is to add the attending persons from the facebook event to this website. The problem is that the attending service needs an access_token. I don't want a user to log in to the app, I just want to use the app access_token. But this doesn't seem to work.

I have the following php code for receiving the access_token:

```
// get facebook auth_token
$FB_APP_ID = '****';
$FB_APP_SECRET = '***';
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $FB_APP_ID . "&client_secret=" . $FB_APP_SECRET . "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
parse_str($app_token); // creates: $access_token
```

In javascript I am using the following code:

```
/**
 * Gets all the attending Users
 * @param function callback: the function to call, when data loading is ready
 * @param function callback: the function to call, when data loading is broken
 * @return void
 */
this.getAttending = function(callback, errorHandler) 
{
    FB.api('/' + this.eventId + '/attending', function(response) {
        if(response.error) {
            errorHandler(response.error['message']);
        } else {
            callback(response.data);
        }
    } , {access_token: facebook.accessToken} );    
}
```

I receive the error: 
Invalid OAuth access token.

The access token looks like:
111737995591905|l9e3niEMM1RsIUhwHZv3pn3c19M

THe user access token looks like:
145634995501895|2.AQBcWfbvdzhloLYc.3600.1312138800.1-1146858041|cjCkHZqquyyFyX2dY0q2YCaSyy0

When i try to use the user access token, everything works fine. But when I hardcode the token, this will not work for other users. When I try the token that the server parsed for me, I get die invalid token action. Does somebody knows a solution for this?
It is a public event, and I don't want the user to login before he/she knows who is attending?

Is this possible at all?
Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you encode the token while hard coding? | should be %7C .
Cant think of anything else that might have gone wrong for the moment

Comment: I did not encode the access_token. This should not be needed, because I call the webservice with the javascript API, and not with an URL. That was also my problem: I've tried to put the expires query variable behind the access_token. Probably this got decoded and returned into an invalid access_token. It seems to work now with the short access_token.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get an access token for yourself and then hard code that in your application (assuming it is running on a secure server where no one else can steal the credentials). Then anyone visiting the page can view the guest list using your own access token which is permissioned to view the list.

The client_credentials grant type is not meant for accessing user data, only application data. I don't know how the rest of the application works but I'm assuming that you need a user access token to see user data.

Comment: Because an access_token has an expiration date. For the moment I have chosen for a javascript solution, because it loads the information asynchronous. So the access token will not be on a secure environment. I don't want the user credentials. I just want to show a picture from the attending people. It is a simple event website, so there is no need to let the app ask for user permissions. Only the public event data is needed.

Comment: It is pretty trivial to build a single API endpoint that serves the list without exposing your access token.

Answer (score 0):

The way i got around this was designating the offline_access permission, it generates an access token that never expires so you can use it indefinitely. You would then in theory authorize only your Facebook account to have the event data pulled from it. You could then view and serve your event details to your website no problem.

Comment: That is rather a dirty walkaround: Everybody will be using MY access_token. It would also be visible for everybody. I don't know if this could be damaging for my account, but I don't like that solution. I have found the solution (look above). Thanx anyway :)

Comment: As long as you define what other permissions you want to grant the app access to (IE events) then as long as you don't mind people being able to see what events you are attending (I can see why this might be a security concern) then it is usually not an issue. In the case I used this, it was for a publicly visible page, that hid no content from anyone, so as you can see, not really an issue. Glad you found a solution however!